# Multiple-file uploader with a file number limit through jQuery or Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am looking for a multiple file uploader that can upload limited number of files with following specifications.

Something like the plugin given below, that shows a upload button as well, and uploads all the files using some jquery or ajax working (without the use of flash) showing a slider to show the uploading in process, and on event complete shows them just below the input box. With a cross shown in some corner with respect to each file, for the user to unselect that particular file.

And also make sure, the number of files doesn't exceeds the provided number.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload

I used this plugin and it does the main job (select multiple files and limit them), but my script fails when the size of the files is too large and they are too many in the number.

Anything that could do the job, near around expected conditions is welcome. Also, the script should be php compatible.

Something that can limit the number of files and upload them to the server and just show them below the input button would do. I will manage the rest. But it should be easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) (link to its demo).

It seems to do all that you are asking for and more. It also works well with PHP. You can set the size limit for files.

It does use Twitter Bootstrap, so it looks great by default. But if you want to change the styling (for example replacing the Cancel button with an X) you should be able to do that in CSS.

- It does not use Flash
- It works with PHP
- It allows you to limit by file size and number of files (see [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-implement-File-Limits))
- It allows you Drag and Drop (not one of your requirements, but cool nonetheless)
- It shows progress for individual files and an overall progress

Comment: its wonderful, but I want something really simple. I am a newbie in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with this plugin and so far it is been great!

www.uploadify.com

Comment: can it do all the things that I want it to do? that too without flash?

Comment: sorry, didn't see that, this one DOES use Flash :S